# Trying to understand this Python code

Tags: python, algorithm, analytics

I'm new to python and I don´t understand **the last line** of this python code. What does it mean?

```
import np as numpy

    def goat_door(prizedoors, guesses):

        #strategy: generate random answers, and
        #keep updating until they satisfy the rule
        #that they aren't a prizedoor or a guess
        result = np.random.randint(0, 3, prizedoors.size)
        while True:
            bad = (result == prizedoors) | (result == guesses)
            if not bad.any():
                return result
            result[bad] = np.random.randint(0, 3, bad.sum())
```

prizedoors and guesses are np.random.choice(2,number of simulations)

Result is an array and I don´t know what result[bad] means.

Edit: I've just write import np as numpy

Comment: I don't think I can answer this unless I have a look at the `np` object. Also, I'm not so sure this is correct python, unless I'm missing something entirely. `bad = ( ) | ( )` will be assigned a boolean value. Booleans in python certainly don't have a `.any()` function. Is this some sort of pseudo-python interpretation?

Comment: `np` appears to be a reference to numpy's random library. See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint

Comment: @clever `np` is referring to numpy, which explains the use or `.any()`

Comment: @Clever Also, `|` is the bitwise-or operator which is different from the standard or (`||`) operator. It is not guaranteed to return a singular boolean value.

Comment: @Mike really? When would | not return a boolean?

Comment: @Clever: `2 | 3`, for example.  In the case of a numpy array, `a = np.arange(10); b = (a <= 1) | (a >= 6)` would give `b = array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)`.

Comment: I see. I hadn't even heard of numpy until 10 minutes ago. Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result` is a numpy `ndarray` of length `prizedoors.size`, where each element is randomly drawn from `[0, 3)`.  For example:

```
>>> result = np.random.randint(0, 3, 5)
>>> result
array([1, 1, 2, 0, 1])
```

`bad` is a boolean array which is True wherever `result == prizedoors` or `result == guesses`.  Probably `prizedoors` and `guesses` are boolean arrays too.  In any case, `bad` will wind  up looking something like

```
>>> bad
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

`bad.sum()` counts the number of Trues:

```
>>> bad.sum()
4
```

`result[bad]` selects the elements of `result` where `bad == True`:

```
>>> result[bad]
array([1, 1, 2, 1])
```

and finally, the last line fills the bad values with new random values (not necessarily good values, only new ones):

```
>>> result[bad] = np.random.randint(0, 3, bad.sum())
>>> result
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Sorry to dig this topic up, but I was wondering if its ok to change bad.sum() to len(result[bad]) ?